# Load MainActivity during Splash Screen

Tags: android, splash-screen

I currently have a `splashScreenActivity` that requires the User the press on a `button` to go to the `MainActivity`.

Would it be possible to load all the contents of `MainActivity` **WITHOUT `MainActivity`'s UI APPEARING ON TOP OF `splashScreenActivity`'s UI** so that when he does presses the button, he is redirected to the `MainActivity` and all the data is 100% loaded?

Thanks in advance

Comment: use splash screen as Layout over other elements. and on click invisible it.

Comment: If you are using service you can start it in the background while you on the splash screen.

Comment: @EliasFazel then he will see the splash every time activity created ?

Comment: Even if main activity set it's layout to its own xml? I tried asynctask but then the mainActivity's layout file just covers my splashscreen layout, as it loads asynchronously @IbrahimAli

Comment: Please try to have an activity for splash and another one for your mainActivity, so your can load your data in you splash with `IntentService` alternatively.

Comment: @IbrahimAli Currently, i have 1 activity for splash and 1 for mainActivity

Comment: then use `IntentService` instead of asyncTask to load your mainactivity data while you in the splash activity.

Comment: @IbrahimAli the problem is that mainactivity runs the following in the onCreate `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` which then just makes it come to the foreground before the user even pressed the button in the SplashScreenActivity

Comment: what condition you set to show splash screen or not set it to visible or invisible that layout

Comment: @EliasFazel currently im not using splash screen as a layout, im using it as an activity because i've attached java functionality with it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found an answer to my problem!

**Note that in my case `MainActivity` can be any activity**

Having a Splash Screen as a `fragment` instead of an `activity` allows you to overlay the `MainActivity` with the `fragment`, while the `MainActivity` data loads in the background.

At this point, whenever you are ready, simply set the visibility of the `fragment` to `View.GONE` or pop it off the fragment stack `getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`, and you will return (never really left) to your `MainActivity` with all the data loaded.

Answer (score 7):

Use Full Screen Dialog With Runnable on Main Activity

```
public void showsplash() {

        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        dialog.setCancelable(true);
        dialog.show();

        final Handler handler  = new Handler();
        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 30000);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`1) Use AsyncTask<> to load all your MainActivity contents in the background while the user is in the SplashScreenActivity. This will help you avoid the extra step of clicking on a button to take you from the SplashScreenActivity to the MainActivity, and this will be handled through the use of Intents. (Refer to working example below)

---

### SplashScreenActivity.java

```
        package foo.foo.load.mainactivity
        
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
        import android.content.res.AssetManager;
        import android.content.res.Configuration;
        import android.os.AsyncTask;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.util.Log;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.List;
        
        public class SplashScreenActivity extends Activity {
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);      
        
                // Make call to execute AsycTasks<> here
                // This helps avoid the extra step of clicking on a button
                // to take you to the MainActivity
                new StartMainActivity().execute(this);
        
                Thread timerThread = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            sleep(2000);
                        } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            // After 2 seconds the Splashscreen will disappear and user is taken to MainActivity
                            Intent splashScreenIntent = new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(splashScreenIntent);
                        }
                    }
                };
        
                timerThread.start();
            }
        
            @Override
            protected void onPause() {
                super.onPause();
                finish();
            }
        
            private class StartMainActivity extends AsyncTask<Context, Void, Intent> {
        
                Context ctx;
        
                @Override
                protected Intent doInBackground(Context... params) {
                    ctx = params[0];
                    AssetManager assetManager = ctx.getAssets();
                    final CBLite cblite = new CBLite(new AndroidContext(ctx), assetManager);
                    
                    // Handle all your MainActivity Contents call here 
                    // Begin MainActivity Content Calls            
                    Image.getImages();
                    Navigation.getMainNavigation();
                    // End MainActivity Content Calls
            
                    Intent in = new Intent();
                    in.setClass(ctx, MainActivity.class);
        
                    return in;
                }
        
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Intent intent) {
                    ctx.startActivity(intent);
                    super.onPostExecute(intent);
                }
        
            }
        }
```

---

### activity_splash.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/splashscreen_background_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/splashScreenMainTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Header Title"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/splashScreenSubTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/splashScreenMainTitle"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Sub Header Title"
            android:visibility="visible"/>
    
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/splashScreenLogo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/splashScreenSubTitle"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

---

### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search" />    
   </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I have tried this. But i can't load MainActivity's contents without the UI appearing on top of my SplashActivity, maybe i am doing something wrong?

Comment: Create 2 separate layout files for each Activity i.e. (1) MainActivity.java is tied to the activity_main.xml file (2) SplashScreenActivity.java is tied to activity_splash.xml. This will ensure the separation of code and stop your MainActivity Contents from being loaded in the SplashScreen UI.

Comment: That's how my setup is currently configured, 1 layout for main, 1 layout for splash, but when i start the main activity with the intent, it calls the setContentView(r.id.******) which is on the onCreate of my MainActivity, and this makes the Main activity overlap the UI of my SplashActivity

Comment: Can you check on both onCreate Methods i.e. for MainActivity and SplashScreenActivity to ensure that their setContentView points to their respective XML files e.g. (1) MainActivity.java points to setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   (2) SplashScreenActivity.java points to setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);   ... Seems like your SplashScreenActivity.java is pointing to setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   ... Thats why its rendering the MainActivity Contents.

Comment: yup, the problem is that i must wait for the user to press on the button (while in SplashScreenActivity), so if i load MainActivity asynchronously from my splash activity, when it get's to the point (1) MainActivity.java loads setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); , the UI of mainActivity will overlap the UI of SplashScreenActivity

Comment: Why don't you remove the SplashScreenActivity button or is it part of the Specs? Reason being that my code above loads the SplashScreen for 2 seconds and then switches automatically to the MainActivity.

Comment: If it were up to me i would... But my client insists that the button be there -_- , thanks again for taking the time to help, really appreciate it